# How to check if a child in a dom node iteration has a specific class name

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So assuming I have this `React` node:

```
  <div className="container">
    <div className="item1">
      Item 1
      <div className="nested">
        <div className="with-discount"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div className="item2">
      Item 2
      <div className="nested"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I would like to iterate over it with something like:
`expect(component.find('.container').map(el => el.getDomNode().[what do I put here to have?]).toEqual([true, false])`, and look for `with-discount` class name. Given that these are child and nested nodes I couldn't find something decent.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with find again. Something like this:

```
expect(component.find('.container').map(el => el.getDomNode().find('.with-discount').exists()).toEqual([true, false])
```

Comment: you can't unfortunately, that was my first attempt